# Searching many-to-many relations with Vici CoolStorage

Tags: coolstorage

For an application used for managing booktitles and such, I'm using CoolStorage as an ORM.

The database has a table named 'titles'. Each title can have n authors, stored in the 'authors' table. The two tables are connected through the linktable 'titles_authors', which is pure.

When I try to filter titles on authors, I get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'QueryExpression' to type 'System.String'

Does anyone know how to filter the titles by author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this up in your Title Class:

```
[ManyToMany("titles_authors", Pure = true, ForeignLinkKey = "AuthorId", LocalLinkKey = "TitleId")]
public abstract CSList<Author> Authors{ get; set; }
```

And vice versa in the Authors class...

Then you can access by:

CSList titlesByAuthor = Title.List("Authour.Name = "Bob Thorn");

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I've done this:
[ManyToMany("titles_authors", ForeignKey = "id", ForeignLinkKey = "author_id", LocalKey = "id", LocalLinkKey = "title_id", Pure = true), Prefetch]
public abstract CSList<Author> Authors { get; set; }

But when I retrieve a list of titles with a filter on author, no titles are returned. Is there something I am doing wrong? I don't get any errors. If you need more information, please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Youve probably solved this. I didnt notice this reply. You need any more help ?